# Spring Boot JPA - Insert (save Method) and Delete (DeleteById) Operations are running for very long time

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa, oracle19c

I am using spring boot 2.3.5 version with Oracle 12c DB and performing the DB operation using spring boot data jpa/hibernate.

Sometimes the DB operation is taking more time and session are blocked for long time and application responding slowly. JPA Repository methods used- saveandflush, deletebyid, save etc.

I have dynatrace linked with the application. In Distributed trace, the DB insert is taking for long time and running for more than 3 mins

Kindly share the steps/guidance to resolve the above issue.

Comment: do the manual queries also take time ? if not its something with the application code.

Comment: Can you share the SQL queries being executed? also, profile with Logging and Tools to Enable SQL logging and use profiling tools to pinpoint the exact causes of slowness. This will help you determine if the issue lies within JPA, database queries, or other areas. Identify Resource-Intensive Queries to Analyze query execution time and resource usage to isolate problematic queries.

Comment: Manual Queries executing faster